# Exceptions is valid for all exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

Maybe this is a stupid question, did Exception accept all?, for example IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidKeySpecException... so when i call this method:

```
public String exception(Exception e){
    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
    return errors.toString();
}
```

it will accept all exceptions and return them with the original exception name?

Thx for all, and sorry for that stupid question i just started java and want to make sure that point.

Comment: Yes. `Exception` is parent class to all Exceptions in java.

Comment: Yes Exception is the base class for all exceptions.

Comment: It will work on  Exceptions, but not on Errors, but then again Errors are not meant to be caught and will happen only when the universe collapses in on itself.

Comment: In the Javadoc you can see the known sub-classes of Exception http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code can handle all `e instanceof Exception`.

`Exception` is the base class of all exceptions, there is a list of **direct** subclasses in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html):

> AclNotFoundException, ActivationException, AlreadyBoundException, ApplicationException, AWTException, BackingStoreException, BadAttributeValueExpException, BadBinaryOpValueExpException, BadLocationException, BadStringOperationException, BrokenBarrierException, CertificateException, CloneNotSupportedException, DataFormatException, DatatypeConfigurationException, DestroyFailedException, ExecutionException, ExpandVetoException, FontFormatException, GeneralSecurityException, GSSException, IllegalClassFormatException, InterruptedException, IntrospectionException, InvalidApplicationException, InvalidMidiDataException, InvalidPreferencesFormatException, InvalidTargetObjectTypeException, IOException, JAXBException, JMException, KeySelectorException, LastOwnerException, LineUnavailableException, MarshalException, MidiUnavailableException, MimeTypeParseException, MimeTypeParseException, NamingException, NoninvertibleTransformException, NotBoundException, NotOwnerException, ParseException, ParserConfigurationException, PrinterException, PrintException, PrivilegedActionException, PropertyVetoException, ReflectiveOperationException, RefreshFailedException, RemarshalException, RuntimeException, SAXException, ScriptException, ServerNotActiveException, SOAPException, SQLException, TimeoutException, TooManyListenersException, TransformerException, TransformException, UnmodifiableClassException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, UnsupportedCallbackException, UnsupportedFlavorException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, URIReferenceException, URISyntaxException, UserException, XAException, XMLParseException, XMLSignatureException, XMLStreamException, XPathException

Answer (score 1):

The super class for all exceptions and errors is `Throwable`. So, I don't know how you will use your method, but for error&exception handling in threads, for example, you should use this one:

`try {
...
} catch (Throwable t) {
...
}`

**UPD**. BTW, nobody restricts create own exception from `Throwable` and throw it instead of `Exception` descendants:

`throw new Throwable() { ... };`

So, you method will not process such exceptions...

Comment: No, you shouldn't, just let Errors go, that's their purpose; they're so abnormal that you shouldn't try to recover from them. You only need to catch Exceptions.

Comment: I'm doing like a text file that contains custom error codes and text and then the the error that normally come up in the console with e.prin....

Comment: @Davio you are deeply wrong. Because if you will not catch `Throwable` inside thread you can never understand why did it died

Comment: @Davio sometimes you really do want to catch `Throwable`, and sometimes you only want to catch `Exception`. It depends on the specific scenario.

Comment: @peti446 yes, it will process all possible kinds of throwable objects (exceptions and errors including)

Comment: @immibis No, Errors usually occur with things like hard disks failing or memory getting corrupted, you shouldn't catch these, because nothing is guaranteed anymore, you can't really do anything (shutting down gracefully for instance) once you caught it.

Comment: @Davio OMG, it seems you have never create multithread systems and debug them.

Comment: @Andremoniy No, I haven't, but if you don't catch something, Java will still dump error information (to your log for instance), so the information is not completely lost. And this approach is usually better than catching and hiding the error and trying to do something with it.

Comment: @Davio again you are deeply wrong about this thought. You **should** catch and process somehow `Throwable` inside separate thread. I don't understand about what we are discussing? You have insufficiency of experience in this question. And I wouldn't take you in my department with such persistence of erroneous views.

Comment: And you should just use `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`. At least you learned something today and I had to read another stupid comment. Please don't waste precious bandwidth on mailing us your resume.